# How to access sd card from computer in marshmallow

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, data-transfer, adoptable-storage

Recently I upgraded my cell phone from Android `Lollipop(5.1.1)` to `Marshmallow(6)`. While setting up the SD card, I choose `Use as internal storage` option. Now when I plugin my cell phone to my computer I can not see any SD card. So I can not read or write in it externally. Is there a way of accessing the SD card contents through data cable from computer?

I need to mention that, I tried with the option `Use as portable storage` but faced with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution of this problem. Each time I connect my phone to my computer I have to go to `Settings` -> `Developer options` -> `Select USB Configuration` and select MTP(Media Transfer Protocol). Then I can access the SD card from my computer. It turns out that whenever its needed to connect the phone and the computer this procedure is to be followed.