# How to access the content of an sd card formatted as internal storage?

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, file-transfer, formatting, adoptable-storage

I am using Cyanogenmod 13 (based on Android 6) and an external 64GB sd card. When starting Cyanogenmod the first time I selected to [format this sd card as an internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137855/how-does-the-format-as-internal-storage-feature-work-in-android-6-0) (Note that in my case the sd card should not be encrypted as I did not enabled device encryption).
Now I want to transfer a big file to my PC. (See: [*File transfer of large file to PC fails*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140771/file-transfer-of-large-file-to-pc-fails) why other file transfer methods did not worked)

So I put the sd card into the sd card slot of my PC, but I noticed that the file system is not recognized. This is what GParted shows:
[image: GParted]

I can read the FAT32 part, but this is not the part Android uses.
**So how I can access this part? What file system does it use?**

Comment: Okay, possibly I am wrong with my encryption theory. If the sd card adoptable storage encryption is independent of the device encryption then I obviously cannot access this data.
In this case this question is a dupe of [*How to access sd card from computer in marshmallow?*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125553/how-to-access-sd-card-from-computer-in-marshmallow)...
Sorry for that.

Comment: I'd say so, yes. You might also wish to see [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575), which has a little tutorial on how to decrypt the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I now today, I think the unfortunate problem is: Even **without** disk encryption Android always encrypts the "internally/adopted storage mounted" sd card.

As such [you need to decrypt that](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125553/how-to-access-sd-card-from-computer-in-marshmallow). The file system used "afterwards" (i.e. inside of the encrypted "container") is, AFAIK, just ext4 or so. Basically a simple file system you can access with Linux.